# Spotfire replicate filter effect on property based filter

Tags: spotfire

I have the tables A and B where A.id = B.id

And for context reasons I must use a property filter with fixed values so in all the visuals elements that I have build I compare the field vs this property and its works nice.

There is one KPI that is built with a expression that uses fields from Table B. The table B hast have the field country so when the user filter by this field, table B should show the values of table B that has de same ID of the table A values that are currently filtered.

This can be easy fixed creating the relation between both tables by the id field and apply the scheme in the visual element. But I cant have 2 filters (the property one and the “relational”).

Any ideas on how can I resolve this?

Any way of replicating the filter effect in the property filter?

Thanks

I tried with intersect expression and changing the table that feeds the visual while filtering by country in the limit expression section